# Run an application as another user in Mac

Tags: macos, unix, administrator, sudo

I have tried various methods mentioned across many sites, but cant able to run perfectly on newer versions of mac os.
I have tried:

```
sudo -i -u otheruser -H
OR
sudo login -f otheruser
```

And try running the app in the new prompt using `/Applications/Sketch.app/Contents/MacOS/Sketch`

Also I have tried:

```
su otheruser -c "/Applications/Sketch.app/Contents/MacOS/Sketch"
```

All of these run the app. But as soon as I open something which require system events (such as requesting macos native file picker) the application crashes. The following error is visible when such events are started.

```
+[NSXPCSharedListener endpointForReply:withListenerName:]: an error occurred while attempting to obtain endpoint for listener 'com.apple.view-bridge': Connection interrupted
```

I have tried with many applications. Exactly same error occurs. Please help.

Comment: With the newer versions of macOS, Apple fixed the bug that allowed you to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am facing this issue on macOS Catalina 10.15.5, latest stable release at the time of writing. Do you, by any chance, mean that the bug was fixed in macOS 11 beta?

Comment: The bug was what allowed it to work, the fix prevents what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can‘t run UI applications as user A while being logged in as user B. The easiest way to get something similar is to enable Fast User Switching and then switch between user A and user B as needed. But each user will have its own Finder etc then, you can‘t use applications on the same screen at once.

Comment: I disagree. There are soo may old forums where they have given the ways to do so. Bu they work on on older versions of mac (2010 - 2017). Even linux allows you to do this easily using `sudo -u`. There must be some way on latest macOS to do this.

Comment: @AnirudhGupta The windowing system on Linux works completely different than on macOS